# Pausing mouse interaction / Locking all items

Tags: events, mouse, paperjs, onmousemove

I'm trying to understand how to pause and resume interaction in paper.js.

I have the [metaball example](http://paperjs.org/examples/meta-balls/) on a page with an input element on top, and because paper.js steals focus for driving the metaball generation `onMouseMove`... bad things happen. Like not able to select what you typed.

I understood I could use `item.locked = true;`, but I don't know what to apply it to because nothing works.

What is the parent Item for paper.js and can I lock it so that everything stops responding to the mouse?

I also couldn't re`attach` the `mousemove` event from the Tool, which is why I came to look into `item.locked`. What's the correct way to remove and reattach mouse events?

Comment: Could you add an example? Because I cannot see your problem when I try to recreate it: http://bit.ly/1jjKBWQ I can easily select what I typed. To stop the metaballs from moving you could add global boolean that controls everything in mousemove and set it to false when an input is active.

Comment: You're right! Only happens in Chrome, selecting with the mouse. Also, if you  drag and reach beyond the canvas selection works.

Should I file a bug report for this?

Comment: I am also using Chrome (Version 32.0.1700.107 on a mac). The question is if the bug should be filed for chrome or paper.js.